# Intersection of a genus g, degree d curve in $\mathbb P^2$ with a line

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $C \subset \mathbb P^2$ be a reduced curve of degree $d$ and geometric genus $g$. Consider all intersections $C \cap L$, where $L$ varies over all lines in $\mathbb P^2$ which are not contained in $C$.

1. What are the possible configurations of $d$ points in $\mathbb P^1$ (upto isomorphism) do we get?
2. What is the dimension of this as a subspace of $\text{Hilb}^d(\mathbb P^1)/PGL_2$?
3. What if we allow $C$ to vary over all degree $d$ genus $g$ curves?

Of course, the problem is only interesting for $d>3$, for $d = 4$ we get that it cannot be 0-dimensional (from existence of bitangents to a quartic), so it must be 1-dimensional.

Comment: If you take C to be 4 lines through a single point x in P2 (d=4), then up to the PGL action, there is only one set of 4 distinct points in P1 that arises. This is clear as the projection from the point x in P2 contracts C to 4 points in P1 and maps any line L which doesn't contain x isomorphically onto P1.

Comment: Even resolving issues like this, it's not really clear what type of answer you are looking for. Are you asking "For which g and d do we get every set of d points in P1 up to the PGL action?" Would you be satisfied if people only considered smooth curves?

Comment: Yeah that kind of pathological special cases is why I think it's better to study it when $C$ is allowed to vary over all degree $d$ genus $g$ curves. Smooth curves have $g = (d-1)(d-2)/2$, I would like an answer for general $g$. Taking them to be nodal would be OK, since a general member will be nodal.

Comment: I found a pretty satisfactory answer in [this paper of Caporaso and Harris][1]. There they study nodal plane curves of a given degree $d$ and genus $g$ passing through $d$ given points on a line.


  [1]: https://arxiv.org/abs/alg-geom/9608025